# itamae で lineinfile 的なことがやりたい

Tags: itamae

Itamae を使ってプロヴィジョニングする際に、 ansible で言うところの [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) をやりたいと思いました。

lineinfile は何かというと、例えば正規表現とファイル、文字列を指定して、ファイルに正規表現の行がなければ、文字列を挿入するようなモジュールです。

#### 質問

- itamae において ansible でいう lineinfile を実現するには、どのように記述するのが通常なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

愚直に、このような形で実行しました。

```
execute 'add line' do
  command "printf '%s\n' #{Shellwords.shellescape CONTENT} >> #{Shellwords.shellescape TARGET_FILE_PATH}"
  not_if "grep -e #{Shellwords.shellescape PATTERN} #{Shellwords.shellescape TARGET_FILE_PATH}"
end
```